# Stripe Does Not Attempt to Contact My Webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am building my first Stripe integration with a Wordpress plugin and cannot get Stripe to attempt to contact my webhook. I have followed the instructions at https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder and successfully made some test payments. Then I copied and pasted the sample code at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders into a file named webhook.php and configured the CLI stripe listen setting with that URL except instead of localhost mine starts with 127.0.0.1. Then I pasted the webhook authentication code into the webhook.php file and made another test payment. It worked fine, but there was no attempt to access the webhook.

What am I missing, is there something I need to add to the sample app from the first URL I listed to instruct the checkout process to ping my server? The sample app does not include a webhook and the page with the fulfillment instructions has no link to any sample app, so I can't tell if I need to add anything more to my create-checkout-session.php file. The Stripe instructions are not very good.

There is also no way to type anything into cmd.exe after it gives me my webhook signing secret. It just has a blinking _ character underneath the line with the secret and anything I try to type anything nothing appears on the screen.

I checked my account on the Stripe website and under the checkout.session.completed event it says "No recent webhook attempts"

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that there are two types of webhook listeners. One is called `Direct` en the other `Connect`.

When you create a webhook you can select the box:  `Listen to events on Connected accounts`. Tick it and you create a `Connect` listener. Don't tick and it's a `Direct` one.

In my case a `charge.succeeded` was only listened to in the `Direct` version of the listener.

Exactly why eludes me. But the support said:

"The first webhook [the Connected type] that you create will inform you regarding the connected accounts."
"And the second one [the Direct type] from your platform"

Comment: OMG thank you... i was looking for that for hours now... This is so confusing lol

Comment: This was so hard to find after numerous attempts to find the resolution to the same issue. Well done and thank goodness you posted this.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like Stripe CLI may not have been running properly; are you following the instructions here?  https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli/webhooks

Comment: This problem was due to a versioning issue. Stripe wrote me back and said that I needed to upgrade the version in my dashboard. I did that, but now even though the webhook is attempting to do something the response says "[500] POST http://" followed by the URL of my webhook.

Comment: That second problem was due to the sample code on the Stripe website missing the following line of code at the top: require 'vendor/autoload.php';